# Remove 'a' from legend when using aesthetics and geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, aesthetics

How can I can remove the letter 'a' from the legend generated by this code? If I remove the `geom_text`, then the 'a' letter will not show in the legend. I want to keep `geom_text`, though.

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, 
                        shape = Species, colour = Species)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_text(aes(label = Species))
```

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Set `show.legend = FALSE` in `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(data = iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species,
           shape = Species, label = Species)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(show.legend = FALSE)
```

The argument `show_guide` changed name to `show.legend` in `ggplot2 2.0.0` ([see release news](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/)).

---

Pre-`ggplot2 2.0.0`:

With `show_guide = FALSE` like so...

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width , colour = Species,
                        shape = Species, label = Species ), size = 20) + 
geom_point() +
geom_text(show_guide  = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Setting `show.legend` to `FALSE` in `ggplot2` 3.2.1 will remove the legend altogether!

Comment: (a) in `ggplot2` 3.3.5 `show.legend=FALSE` preserves the overall legend and (b) I am surprised at how difficult  finding this was

Comment: This does not seem to work when the aes() part is included inside geom.txt and returns "Ignoring unknown aesthetics: show.legend"

Comment: @Markm0705 that sounds like you put `show.legend = FALSE` **inside** `aes()`. It should be inside `geom_text()`, but not inside `aes()`. So `geom_text(aes(label = Species), show.legend = FALSE)` is good, `geom_text(aes(label = Species, show.legend = FALSE))` is bad.

Answer (score 35):

We can use `guide_legend(override.aes = aes(...))` to hide the 'a' in the legend.

Below is a short example of how you might use [guide_legend()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html)

```r
library(ggrepel)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

d <- mtcars[c(1:8),]

p <- ggplot(d, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) +
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(label = rownames(d), fill = factor(cyl)),
    size = 5, color = "white"
  )

# Let's see what the default legend looks like.
p
```

[image]

```r
# Now let's override some of the aesthetics:
p + guides(
  fill = guide_legend(
    title = "Legend Title",
    override.aes = aes(label = "")
  )
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the accepted one, as it allows to specifically remove the 'a' letter from the legend, while other aesthetics can, if desired, remain untouched.

Comment: In case that color is used instead of fill it could be `guides( color = guide_legend(override.aes = aes(label = "")))`

Answer (score 17):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441765/ggplot2-messes-up-the-graph-legend). Simon's solution worked for me but a slight twist was required. I did not realise that I need to **add** "show_guide = F" to geom_text's arguments, rather than replace with it the existing arguments - which is what Simon's solution shows. For a ggplot2 noob like me this was not that obvious. A proper example would have used the OP's code and just added the missing argument like this:

```
..
geom_text(aes(label=Species), show_guide = F) +
..
```

Comment: This worked for me, but `show_guide` is now deprecated. Use `show.legend` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Like Nick said

the following code would still produce the error:

```
geom_text(aes(x=1,y=2,label="",show_guide=F))
```

[image]

whereas:

```
geom_text(aes(x=1,y=2,label=""),show_guide=F)
```

outside the aes argument eliminates the a over the legend

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to customize the 'a' to something else like 'r'?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, with an 'a' appearing behind different coloured points I was trying to label with `geom_text_repel`. To remove the 'a', so that it would just show the point without the 'a' behind it, I had to add `show.legend=FALSE` as an argument in `geom_text_repel`.

Hope that makes sense to anyone who might be labouring with the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `show.legend = FALSE` in the arguments of `geom_label_repel()` to remove the "a" in the legend. 
So, instead of

```
ggplot(d, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) +
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(label = rownames(d), fill = factor(cyl)),
    size = 5, color = "white"
  )+ guides(
  fill = guide_legend(
    title = "Legend Title",
    override.aes = aes(label = "")
  )
)
```

you can do,

```
ggplot(d, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) +
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(label = rownames(d), fill = factor(cyl)),
    size = 5, color = "white",
    show.legend = FALSE  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off the top answer. If you only wanted the `geom_text()` to be visible but have that `geom_point()` for the purposes of your legend you could set the alpha to 0 making it invisible but override it to 1 in the guides to force it to show.

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, 
                        shape = Species, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Species)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = aes(label = "", alpha = 1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, even I'm nob.

`stat_cor()` also needs `show.legend=FALSE` to avoid "a".

Wasted time for me... ;)

Many thanks for all your contributions