# Legend is displaying additional shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggpubr

I'm using the following data frame:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Genotype = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
2L,2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L,1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
.Label= c("miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 cKO"), class = "factor"), 
Tissue = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("iLN", "Spleen", "Skin", "Colon"), class = "factor"), 
`Cells/SC/Live/CD8—,, CD4+/Foxp3+,Median,<BV421-A>,CD127` = c(518L, 
715L, 572L, 599L, 614L, 881L, 743L, 722L, 779L, 843L, 494L, 
610L, 613L, 624L, 631L, 925L, 880L, 932L, 876L, 926L, 1786L, 
2079L, 2199L, 2345L, 2360L, 2408L, 2509L, 3129L, 3263L, 3714L, 
917L, NA, 1066L, 1059L, 939L, 1269L, 1047L, 974L, 1048L, 
1084L)),
.Names = c("Genotype", "Tissue", "Cells/SC/Live/CD8—,,CD4+/Foxp3+,Median,<BV421-A>,CD127"),
row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and trying to make a plot using ggplot2 where box plots and points are displayed grouped by "Tissue" and interleaved by "Genotype". This seems to be working well, however, I'm noticing that in my legend, there is an additional "a" that is being overlaid with the shape.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
color.groups <- c("black","red")
names(color.groups) <- unique(df1$Genotype)
shape.groups <- c(16, 1)
names(shape.groups) <- unique(df1$Genotype)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Tissue, y = df1[3], color = Genotype, shape = Genotype)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(), outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  ylim(0,1.2*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE)) +
  ylab('MFI CD127 (of CD4+ Foxp3+ T cells') +
  scale_color_manual(values=color.groups) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=shape.groups) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.title.x=element_blank(), aspect.ratio = 1,
                     text = element_text(size = 9)) +
  stat_compare_means(label = 'p.format', method = 't.test',
                     label.y = c(0.1*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE) + max(df1[3][c(1:10),], na.rm = TRUE),
                                 0.1*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE) + max(df1[3][c(11:20),], na.rm = TRUE),
                                 0.1*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE) + max(df1[3][c(21:30),], na.rm = TRUE),
                                 0.1*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE) + max(df1[3][c(31:40),], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

[image]

If I hide the scale_color_manual legend, it removes the "a"s but it also removes the color from the legend. Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to add `show.legend = FALSE` in `stat_compare_means`. See also [Remove 'a' from legend when using aesthetics and geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337653/remove-a-from-legend-when-using-aesthetics-and-geom-text)

Comment: I ran your code with and without `scale_color_manual` and the `a`s are present on both runs.

Comment: @Henrik It worked! Care to explain why?

Comment: `stat_compare_means` inherits the mapping from the top level in `ggplot`, not only `x` and `y`, but also `color = Genotype`. Although the `text` from `stat_compare_means` is not colored by Genotype in the plot, the default `geom_text` symbol for legend (the "a") is still added to the legend. Seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: Seems like strange behavior but thank you, it worked perfectly!