# Change geom_text's default "a" legend to label string itself

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-text

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337653/remove-a-from-legend-when-using-aesthetics-and-geom-text), I want to change the default "a" in the legend, but rather than removing it completely, I want to replace it with the labels themselves. That is, the first line of the legend should have a colored icon labeled "se" with the full name "setosa" on the right.

```r
iris$abbrev = substr( iris$Species, 1, 2 )
     
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, 
                        shape = Species, colour = Species)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = abbrev))
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change the legend key generating function. This still requires a bit of manual intervention, but arguably less than using the grobs.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

data(iris)
iris$abbrev = substr( iris$Species, 1, 2 )

oldK <- GeomText$draw_key # to save for later

# define new key
# if you manually add colours then add vector of colours 
# instead of `scales::hue_pal()(length(var))`
GeomText$draw_key <- function (data, params, size, 
                               var=unique(iris$abbrev), 
                               cols=scales::hue_pal()(length(var))) {

    # sort as ggplot sorts these alphanumerically / or levels of factor
    txt <- if(is.factor(var)) levels(var) else sort(var)
    txt <- txt[match(data$colour, cols)]

    textGrob(txt, 0.5, 0.5,  
             just="center", 
             gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), 
                       fontfamily = data$family, 
                       fontface = data$fontface, 
                       fontsize = data$size * .pt))
}

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, 
                      shape=Species, colour=Species)) +  
  geom_text(aes(label = abbrev))


# reset key
GeomText$draw_key <- oldK
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can work on grobs as follows:

```
p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape =
Species, colour = Species)) +  geom_text(aes(label = abbrev))

g <- ggplotGrob(p)
lbls <- unique(iris$abbrev)
g$grobs[[15]][[1]][[1]]$grobs[[4]]$label <- lbls[1]
g$grobs[[15]][[1]][[1]]$grobs[[6]]$label <- lbls[2]
g$grobs[[15]][[1]][[1]]$grobs[[8]]$label <- lbls[3]

library(grid)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: What is `[[15]][[1]][[1]]` here?

Comment: @JackBrookes `g$grobs[[15]]` is the `guide-box` TableGrob (i.e. the legend) and `g$grobs[[15]][[1]]` is a list with the `guides` TableGrob as a first element. The text elements of the legend are collected inside `g$grobs[[15]][[1]][[1]]`

Comment: Good lord. Well, it definitely works! As a note to others generalizing this to other ggplots, you'll need to replace the "15" index by looking at your `g$grobs` to find the one starting with `TableGrob (5 x 5) "guide-box"`.

Comment: @half-pass ; you can find the grobs by looking at the names ie `g$grobs[[grep("guide", g$layout$name)]]`