# How to have "a" removed from a ggraph plot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

Can the letter "a" be removed from the legend associated with e.g. a `fill` or `colour` aesthetic, in a `ggraph` network plot, like in the simple example below ?

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

g1 <- make_ring(6)
vertex_attr(g1) <- list(name = LETTERS[1:6],  type =rep(c("typeA", "typeB", "typeC"), 2))

ggraph(g1) + geom_node_label(aes(label = name, fill = type)) + 
  geom_edge_diagonal() + theme_graph()
```

In the case of `geom_text`, `show.legend = FALSE` solves it,

[Remove 'a' from legend when using aesthetics and geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337653/remove-a-from-legend-when-using-aesthetics-and-geom-text)

but adding `show.legend = FALSE` within `geom_node_label()`, removes the legend completely.

is there any solution for this in `ggraph`?

Comment: change the key to `GeomLabel$draw_key <- function (data, params, size) {
    grobTree(draw_key_rect(data))
}` and redraw  . [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965758/change-geom-texts-default-a-legend-to-label-string-itself/49966784#49966784)

Comment: (ps you will need `library(grid)`) . actually you can use `GeomLabel$draw_key <- function (data, params, size) {
    draw_key_rect(data)
}`

Comment: this worked, thank you @user20650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the original question based on comments above:
The following line of code has to be added on the top of the script as per @user20650 solution.

```
library(grid)
GeomLabel$draw_key <- function (data, params, size) { draw_key_rect(data) }
```

If `repel = TRUE` argument is used inside `geom_node_label`, then in addition to the above `GeomLabelRepel$draw_key <- GeomLabel$draw_key` needs to be added.