# Why does text appear in the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
set.seed(1234)
ss <- sample(1:32, 10)
df <- mtcars[ss, ]

ggplot(df, aes(wt, mpg))+ geom_point(col = "red") + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = rownames(df), fill = factor(cyl)), size = 5,
                   hjust = 1,fontface = 3)
```

In the legend, why does 'a' appear alongside, 4,6,8?[image]

Comment: Related: [Remove 'a' from legend when using aesthetics and geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337653/remove-a-from-legend-when-using-aesthetics-and-geom-text)

Comment: this may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989158/how-to-have-a-removed-from-a-ggraph-plot-legend

Comment: @Henrik true. Of note though (even if that was not in the OP's question), the solutions offered there do not work to remove the `a` with `ggrepel` (they remove the legend altogether). @user20650's link might offer a way to remove it (works with `ggraph` but I did not test it with `ggrepel`)

Comment: @Henrik, this removes the legend altogether

Answer (score 5):

`a` symbolizes the text added by `geom_label_repel()` and it matches the font, colour, etc. of your labels.

The picture below shows one of the demo examples of the `ggrepel` package shown in the package examples vignette:

[image]

You can see the same thing, but with different options passed as arguments to `geom_label_repel()`.

If you actually want to remove the letter "a" from the legend you can redefine the legend key as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989158/how-to-have-a-removed-from-a-ggraph-plot-legend?answertab=votes#tab-top):

```
# save original legend key for later
oldK <- GeomLabelRepel$draw_key

# define new key without the text label
library(grid)
GeomLabelRepel$draw_key <- function (data, params, size) { draw_key_rect(data) }

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(wt, mpg))+ geom_point(col = "red") + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = rownames(df), fill = factor(cyl)), size = 5,
                  fontface = 3)

# reset key
GeomLabelRepel$draw_key <- oldK
```

Comment: prosoitos : I hope its okay including the edit to your answer -- if not, please roll back

Comment: Fine by me. The OP was not asking how to remove those `a`, but I am sure that it will be useful, either to them or to others and thus makes for a better answer. Thank you for checking :)