# Change "a" in geom_label_repel in R to something else and not just delete it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change (not to remove) the "a" that gets displayed by geom_label_repel in the legend. I already found the following Thread: [Why does text appear in the legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348955/why-does-text-appear-in-the-legend/53349043) that told me how to remove it.

```
library(ggrepel)

data <- data.frame(xVal,yVal, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=xVal, y=yVal)) +
      geom_point() + 
      geom_label_repel( aes( label=pointName, fill=factor( yVal ) ), nudge_x = 1.25, nudge_y = 1.2 ) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=colorPallet, labels = yVal)
```

This Code gives me the following image: 
[image]

I want to change it so that the "a" in the legend is displaying the numbers i have in the vector *pointName*. (that are the numbers in the nicture that range from 48 to 96).

Thank you all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have "a" removed from a ggraph plot legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989158/how-to-have-a-removed-from-a-ggraph-plot-legend)

Comment: I dont want to remove the "a" i want to change it.

Comment: The answer to that question shows a way to change it.

Comment: @NelsonGon could you explain to me how? i dont see where i would need to add something to be able to change it. Or lets say i am sure it is in the drawKey function, but idk what to add. thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove 'a' from legend when using aesthetics and geom\_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337653/remove-a-from-legend-when-using-aesthetics-and-geom-text)

Comment: I think the above duplicate might have a more clear answer.

Comment: @divibisan geom_text is not the same as geom_label, as there i would need the solution posted by NelsonGon. But both solutions only remove the "a" and i want it to display something else. SO instead of having the "a" there i want, lets say a "b" or a "42" or something along those lines. I thought if the "a" is there, there needs to be a way to change it but all i found where solutions to remove it.

Comment: I see, my mistake. I think you might have to do something hacky with your legend, since I believe the letter 'a' is actually a shape from the ggplot shapes list, not text, so you would not be able to change it into something more than a single character.

Comment: It might help if you add a reproducible example of your data using `dput`. Then, at least, we could play around with your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Guides for `geom_text()` now accept custom labels with
`guide_legend(override.aes = list(label = "foo"))` (@brianwdavis, #2458)."

As per [release 3.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.0.0).

So here you'd use `scale_fill_manual(values=colorPallet, labels = yVal, guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(label = "foo")))`.

Comment: Thank you, thats what i was looking for. As a note for everyone curious, you can replace "foo" also with a vector and it will use the values in it.