# Position a ggplot Legend label directly over its fill colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a ggplot graph, I wish to have the values of the legend (here, 0 and 1) to be positioned over the colours they represent, and not to the side of them. By which I mean not to the left, right, above or below the coloured square, but within the square itself. This would result in a number 0 inside a red square and the number 1 inside a blue square. How can this be done?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
geom_bar() +
theme(legend.position = "top", 
    legend.direction = "horizontal") +
guides(color = guide_legend(title.position = "left", label.position = "top"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using `fill` you need to use fill within `guides` then play with `label.vjust` and `title.vjust` to get everything to line up.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.vjust = -7, label.position = "top", title.vjust = 0.2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With minor adjustment, you can use the approach shown at [change-geom-texts-default-a-legend-to-label-string-itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965758/change-geom-texts-default-a-legend-to-label-string-itself?answertab=votes#tab-top). This changes the key generating function, and so allows `ggplot2` to calculate the positions to place the labels for you.

Th idea is to keep the original `rectGrob` for the `geom_bar` legend key and use an additional `textGrob` to place the label on top.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

oldK <- GeomBar$draw_key # to save for later

# see other answer on how to tweak function based n manual colours
GeomBar$draw_key <- function (data, params, size, 
                              var=unique(mtcars$vs),
                              cols=scales::hue_pal()(length(var))) {

    # match labels to the fill colour
    txt <- if(is.factor(var)) levels(var) else sort(var)
    txt <- txt[match(data$fill, cols)]

    # This is from the original GeomBar$draw_key -------------------
    lwd <- min(data$size, min(size)/4)
    rg <- rectGrob(width = unit(1, "npc") - unit(lwd, "mm"), height = unit(1, 
        "npc") - unit(lwd, "mm"), gp = gpar(col = data$colour, 
        fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha), lty = data$linetype, 
        lwd = lwd * .pt, linejoin = "mitre"))
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------

    # Add text label: lifted from other answer
    # hard-coded text size multiplier -- got to be a better way!
    tg <- textGrob(txt, 0.5, 0.5,  
             just="center", 
             gp = gpar(col = "black", 
                       fontfamily = data$family, 
                       fontface = data$fontface, 
                       fontsize = 10*data$size * .pt)) 
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------

    grobTree(rg, tg) # output new key
}
```

You can then plot

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top", 
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.text = element_blank())

# reset key function to original
GeomBar$draw_key <- oldK
```

[image]

This should be fairly robust to resizing your plot.