# Problem with geom_text and caption in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm creating a graphic using ggplot2 and I am having difficulty with the subtitle when I use the geom_text function because it is "a" instead of just the colored ball.
Here's an example

```
  head(iris,3)
  kIris <- 3
  iris.kMeans <- kmeans(iris[,1:4], kIris, nstart=20)
  IrisAgrupado <- data.frame(iris, cluster=factor(iris.kMeans$cluster))
  ggplot(IrisAgrupado, aes(x=Petal.Width,y=Sepal.Width,color=cluster, label=Species)) +
  geom_point(color="white")+
  geom_text()
```

[How is the final result of the graph the problem is in the "a" of the caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slb5I.png)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Please in english

Comment: Related: [Remove 'a' from legend when using aesthetics and geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337653/remove-a-from-legend-when-using-aesthetics-and-geom-text)

Answer (score 0):

`library(ggplot)`
`library(ggrepel)`

dataframe:

```
  kIris <- 3
  iris.kMeans <- kmeans(iris[,1:4], kIris, nstart=20)
  IrisAgrupado <- data.frame(iris, cluster=factor(iris.kMeans$cluster))
```

plot code:

```
ggplot(IrisAgrupado, aes(x=Petal.Width,y=Sepal.Width,color= Species)) + geom_point(aes(colour = Species))+ scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "yellow")) + geom_text_repel(show.legend = FALSE, aes(label = Species))
```

Why this works:
`show.legend = FALSE` removes the 'a' values. Then you can perform the aesthetics.

output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Meilton. How do I get the strokes connecting the dots?

Comment: Should be the function `geom_text_repel` from the `ggrepel` package. You may first need to install it - `install.packages(ggrepel)`. It allows for labels when clustered points not to overlap. Hope that helps! Feel free to accept this as the answer if it has answered your question.