# Remove overlapping glyphs in legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2_3.4.1` and `ggrepel_0.9.3` with `R/4.2.2`.  Below is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
# Construct data frame
sampDF <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:12, 1.5*(1:12), 1:12))
labelV <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l")
colnames(sampDF) <- c("x", "y", "group")
sampDF <- cbind(sampDF, labelV)
# Plot.  Set labelV as a factor so we get discrete colors 
p<-ggplot(sampDF, aes(x, y, shape=as.factor(labelV), 
                     color=as.factor(labelV), label=labelV), size=5) +
   geom_point() +
   scale_shape_manual(values = 1:12) +
   geom_text_repel(data=sampDF, box.padding=0.5,
                   min.segment.length = unit(0, 'lines'),
                  max.overlaps=Inf)
plot(p)
```

Yields :

[image]

Question :

1. How do I get ggplot to stop overwriting the letter `a` over each glyph in the legend?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337653/remove-a-from-legend-when-using-aesthetics-and-geom-text. You need to add `show.legend = FALSE` to your geom_text_repel layer.