# Add labels to top of barplot with condition.

Tags: r, plot

I have a barplot that looks like this:

[image]

I need to add the names to the top of the bars. But I only wish to label the names that are above the horizontal 0.5 line.

I can add labels as follows:

```
 xx <- barplot(....)
 text(xx, data$features, labels=data$features, pos=3, offset=.5)
```

But this of course adds all values.

Comment: @user20650 You probably mean `text(xx, ifelse(data$features> 0.5, data$features, 0), labels=ifelse(data$features> 0.5, data$features, ""))`

Comment: using `ggplot2` you can use an `ifelse` in the label argument [similar solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15625149/4002530)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
set.seed(1)
y <- round(rnorm(10),1)
xx <- barplot(y)
yy <- y[y>.5]
xx <- xx[y>.5]
text(xx, yy, labels=yy, pos=3, offset=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: the labels all appear on the left squished together. They don't hover above their respective bar.

Comment: I updated my post, it kind of works for me. You'll have to adapt to your stack width