# Remove line in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

How can I remove the line that crosses the blue point on my legend?
I was able to remove the dots from items number 1 and 2 by using

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(NA,NA,16))))
```

but can't remove the line from the third item. Thanks beforehand.

[image]

Below is the code I am using....

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
white.st2 <- structure(list(Year = c(1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009
), ws_est_abundance = c(NA, 18257, 144672, NA, NA, 143795, 98717, 
NA, NA, 57641, 32283, NA, NA, 55180, 124844, 175981, 100915, 
90702), perc_ws_pop = c(NA, 3.789, 4.418, NA, NA, 8.129, 9.088, 
NA, NA, 8.898, 8.595, NA, NA, 5.252, 5.599, 6, 6.2, 6.899), est_ws_abundance = c(NA, 
692, 6392, NA, NA, 11689, 8971, NA, NA, 5129, 2775, NA, NA, 2898, 
6991, 10559, 6257, 6258)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(white.st2,aes(Year,est_ws_abundance)) + geom_point(aes(color="Estimated abundance\n of 15-year 
old white sturgeon"),size=3) + labs(x="", y="Number of 15-Year Old\n White Sturgeon",title='Estimated 
Abundance of 15-Year old White Sturgeon\n In San Pablo and Suisun Bays, 1992-2009') + theme_bw() + 
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=5500,color='1967-1991 average')) + 
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=11000,color='AFRP production target'),size=0.7) + 
theme(legend.position='bottom',
legend.direction = "horizontal",legend.title = element_blank()) + 
scale_y_continuous(labels=comma,breaks=seq(0,13000,1000))  + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1992, 
2009, 1)) + guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(NA,NA,16)))) +
    scale_colour_manual("", breaks = c("1967-1991 average", "AFRP production target","Estimated 
abundance\n of 15-year old white sturgeon"),values = c("green", "red","blue"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer, you can override the linetype also.

[Remove lines from color and fill legends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941900/remove-lines-from-color-and-fill-legends)

So add `linetype=c(1,1,NA)` to the `override.aes` list. In other words change your:

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(NA,NA,16))))
```

to:

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(NA,NA,16), linetype=c(1,1,NA))))
```

Comment: Honestly, as an easier option I normally use a annotate line and text rather than geom_hline which also gets my line label directly in the graph ... but that's just my preference

Comment: @ Michael Tallino, Thank you. I tried many options but didn't think of linetype. I didn't know about annotate line. Do you have an example of that? I will be interested on that for the future.

Comment: @Salvador not super handy - but basically you just use the ggplot2 annotate to make a line that spans the whole graph and another annotate for the text. Similar to this code but change x=0,xend=10,y=2.2 or something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158006/how-to-annotate-the-line-at-ggplot