# Add a label or geom_text to scatter plot - R/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add a label/geon_text to every point that will include its dataframe index and  the xvar and yvar values (for example the label for the first one will be (“Point 1: 500,570”)?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2))

xvar <- c(500,450,490,560,618, 660,700,650, 590,550)
yvar <- c(570,600,650,670,660,650,630,580,570,550)
dat <- data.frame(xvar,yvar)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + geom_point(shape=1)
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624656/label-points-in-geom-point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Label points in geom\_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624656/label-points-in-geom-point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable label and plot it to `geom_text()`:

library(ggplot2)

```
> xvar <- c(500,450,490,560,618, 660,700,650, 590,550)
> yvar <- c(570,600,650,670,660,650,630,580,570,550)
> dat <- data.frame(xvar,
                    yvar)

> dat$point <- sprintf("Point %s",
                       seq(from = 1,
                           to = length(xvar)))

> dat$labvar <- sprintf("%s: %s, %s",
                        dat$point,
                        dat$xvar,
                        dat$yvar)

> dat
   xvar yvar    point             labvar
1   500  570  Point 1  Point 1: 500, 570
2   450  600  Point 2  Point 2: 450, 600
3   490  650  Point 3  Point 3: 490, 650
4   560  670  Point 4  Point 4: 560, 670
5   618  660  Point 5  Point 5: 618, 660
6   660  650  Point 6  Point 6: 660, 650
7   700  630  Point 7  Point 7: 700, 630
8   650  580  Point 8  Point 8: 650, 580
9   590  570  Point 9  Point 9: 590, 570
10  550  550 Point 10 Point 10: 550, 550

> ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar,
                  y=yvar)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = labvar),
              hjust = -0.05,
              vjust = 0.05) +
    geom_point(shape = 1)
```

[image: labelled graph]

Answer (score 0):

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(ggrepel)
 library(dplyr)

 xvar <- c(500,450,490,560,618, 660,700,650, 590,550)
 yvar <- c(570,600,650,670,660,650,630,580,570,550)
 dat <- data.frame(xvar,yvar, xindex = seq_along(xvar)) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(label = paste0("x: ", xvar, ", y:", yvar, ", index: ", xindex))

 ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + geom_point(shape=1)  + 
   geom_text_repel(aes(label = label))
```