# Plot labels at end of lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need a plot with more than two variables, for that, I change my data frame with `melt` and I used `ggplot2`. I would like to put the label at the end of each line, I used `ggrapel` but instead of that I get a lot of labels, I appreciate any help.

Here the code:

```
obs1 <- melt(obs, id.vars = "Profundidad")

ggplot(obs1, aes(Profundidad, value, col = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = dath) +
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
    legend.position = "none")+
  labs(x =" Profundidad de secuenciación", y = "ASVs observados")+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = variable),
    nudge_x = 0.1, 
    na.rm = FALSE)
```

And I get this:

[image: plot result]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is `obs1`? Could you please `dput(obs1)` and paste the result in your question by editing it!

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163736/direct-labels-puts-labels-at-wrong-place/63169541#63169541 answers your question.

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359816/12400385

Comment: Check out this:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/label-geom-line-with-a-label/71035/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that should clarify how you can put the label at the end of each line.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)

# Create a dataset similar to your obs1
n <- 10
obs1 <- data.frame(Profundidad=rep(seq(0, 20000, length.out=n), n),
                   value = rep(sqrt(0:9),n)*rep(1:10, each=n),
                   variable=factor(rep(1:10, each=n)))

# Find the x and y position of the last point for each line
xy_labs <- obs1 %>%
           group_by(variable) %>%
           summarize(pos = which.max(Profundidad),
                     x = Profundidad[pos],
                     y = value[pos])

ggplot(obs1, aes(Profundidad, value, group=variable, col = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5)+
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
    legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x =" Profundidad de secuenciación", y = "ASVs observados")+
  geom_label_repel(data=xy_labs, aes(x=x, y=y, label = y), 
    nudge_x = 0.1, inherit.aes=F, 
    na.rm = FALSE)
```

[image]