# ggplot: plot a simple function without using a dataframe and add latex point labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add labels to each point in a simple plot in R. I can do it via the `plot` function. The code below works and achieves what I want to a point.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

i = 20
j = 200
x1 = seq(i, j, 40)
y1 = exp(-0.02*x1)
point.names = c(TeX('$t_{j-2}$'), TeX('$t_{j-1}$'), TeX('$t_j$'), TeX('$t_{j+1}$'), TeX('$t_{j+2}$'))

plot(x1, y1, cex=1.5, col='blue', pch = 21, bg = "blue", xlim=c(0, 220))
lines(x1, y1, lwd=1, col='blue')
text(x1, y1, labels=point.names, cex=1.5, pos=4)
```

Ultimately, I want to plot 3 of these curves on the same graph and as far as I know, `ggplot2` is what I need. I am able to plot the graph via `ggplot` but I am unable to add the labels to the points.

Here is a `ggplot` plot that works but it does not add point labels:

```
i = 20
j = 200
x1 = seq(i, j, 40)
y1 = exp(-0.02*x1)
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x1, y1)) + geom_point(aes(x1, y1), size=6, col='blue')
```

To add point labels, I found this post: [Label points in geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624656/label-points-in-geom-point)
which suggests I need to add `label=point.names` and `+geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0)`

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x1, y1)) + geom_point(aes(x1, y1, label=point.names), size=6, col='blue') + geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

Unfortunately this results in:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type <expression>. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.
✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
✖ `label = point.names`
ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add `after_stat()`?
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In geom_point(aes(x1, y1, label = point.names), size = 6, col = "blue") :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
```

OK, so it can't deal with the `point.names` because it is `latex2exp` expressions. So I tried with simple labels:

```
my.labs = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x1, y1)) + geom_point(aes(x1, y1, label=my.labs), size=6, col='blue') + geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

Unfortunately, I still get a warning message and no labels on the plot.

```
Warning message:
In geom_point(aes(x1, y1, label = my.labs), size = 6, col = "blue") :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
```

Any idea how I can get latex labels on this plot?

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if you would like to try `geom_richtext` of `ggtext`, with `point_names` changed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
i <- 20
j <- 200
x1 <- seq(i, j, 40)
y1 <- exp(-0.02 * x1)
point_names <- c("t<sub>j-2</sub>", "t<sub>j-1</sub>", "t<sub>j</sub>", "t<sub>j+1</sub>", "t<sub>j+2</sub>")

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x1, y1)) +
  geom_point(aes(x1, y1), size = 12, col = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_richtext(aes(x1, y1, label = point_names), fill = NA, label.color = NA)
```

[image]