# ggplot2 legend only in a plot

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to show the legend only in the plot? I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041042/how-to-plot-just-the-legends-in-ggplot2) but didn't work:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

coverage_plot <- ggplot(data=m, aes(x=Time, y=Coverage, group=Technique, color=Technique)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Technique") +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Technique, colour = Technique), show.legend = T, size=3) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = seq(1, 30.0, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),text = element_text(size=14),legend.title=element_blank())+
  labs(x = "Time (minutes)")+
  scale_shape_discrete() +
  guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=3, linetype=0)))

mylegend<-g_legend(coverage_plot)
p3 <- grid.draw(mylegend)
```

The `p3` here return null!

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish I could comment..
Anyway, I tried your code with the `diamonds` dataset form `ggplot2` and there it works fine. You think you can share your data?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

coverage_plot <- ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, group=clarity, color=clarity)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(name="clarity") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = clarity), show.legend = T, size=3) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = seq(1, 30.0, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),text = element_text(size=14),legend.title=element_blank())+
  labs(x = "Time (minutes)")+
  scale_shape_discrete() +
  guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=3, linetype=0)))

mylegend<-g_legend(coverage_plot)
p3 <- grid.draw(mylegend)
```

I removed the `shape` from `geom_point` since there where only 6 shape symbols and `diamonds` has 8 variables. But other than that it's the same.