# Legend changing the size of ggplot figure in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, size, legend

I have a ggplot in Shiny, which uses geom_point to plot some data. I have it setup so that when a checkbox is checked, an aesthetic is added which colours the data into two separate variables. This also creates a legend. My problem is that when this legend appears, it 'takes' space from the plot and the plot becomes slightly smaller. Is there a way I can fix the size of the plot so that the legend appears without altering the plot size?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Transfers Analysis App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("Outage", "Show Outages", FALSE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1", height = "600px", width = "100%", hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot_hover")),
      verbatimTextOutput("hover_info")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    Outage <- input$Outage

    g <- ggplot(data, aes(Date, NUMBER_OF_TRANSFERS)) + geom_point() 

    if (Outage == TRUE) 
      g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = Outage))  + scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("Outage", "No Outage", "Day After an Outage", "Both"), name= "Legend", values=c( "black", "red", "blue")) + theme(legend.position="bottom")

    plot(g)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

note: my actual code has a lot more features in than this which I have cut out for simplicity.

Comment: Since you are going the extra mile, can you make sure your code is actually able to run? (Syntax and data.)

Comment: Data is missing here, plus few brackets...

Comment: Sorry for the quality of my code (I'm new to both stack and R), I'm not sure if I am able to provide the data as this is a company project I'm working on. I realise this doesn't help much but I thought maybe someone might be able to tell me where I'm going wrong or suggest some functions/techniques just by looking at my code alone? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe someone has a better idea but here is a suggestion. You could plot only the legend of the same graphic. You did not provide a dataset so I am using the iris dataset as an example. If you click on outage it will produce a legend at the bottom of the first graph. If unclick, it will produce a blank plot you won't see. As you can see the legend will not change the size of your first graph.

Using this post ([How to plot just the legends in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041042/how-to-plot-just-the-legends-in-ggplot2)), you could:

```
#function to extract the legend
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){ 
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot)) 
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box") 
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]] 
  return(legend)} 

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Transfers Analysis App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("Outage", "Show Outages", FALSE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1", height = "600px", width = "100%", hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot_hover")),
      plotOutput("plot2"),
      verbatimTextOutput("hover_info")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    Outage <- input$Outage

    g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() 

    if (Outage == TRUE) 
      g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = Species))  + scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), values=c( "black", "red", "blue")) + 
      theme(legend.position="none") 
    plot(g)

  })


  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

    Outage <- input$Outage

    if (Outage == TRUE) {
      g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() 

      g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = Species))  + scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), name= "Legend", values=c( "black", "red", "blue")) + 
        theme(legend.position="bottom") +
        theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15)) # you can change the size of the legend

      legend <- g_legend(g) 
      grid.draw(legend) 
    } else {
      g <- ggplot()  + theme_bw(base_size=0) +
        theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
              panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.border = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_blank()) 

      plot(g)
    }

  })  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Great, it's working! Any idea how to move it closer to the graph?

Comment: No worries, I figured it out (I added ' height = "100px" ' to my second plot output  in the UI section)