# ggplot2: multiple plots with different variables in a single row, single grouping legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

While there are some topics going in the same general direction, I haven't found any that would deal with my issue specifically. Hence a new topic, and thanks in advance for all the help.

**Situation**

I have two plots, that need to go in a single figure horizontally, e.g.:

```
library(ggplot2)
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]    
p1 <- qplot(price, carat, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)
p2 <- qplot(price, depth, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)
```

While the dependent variable differs per plot, the grouping and the independent remains the same. Hence I only need but a single legend in the figure to describe the groups.

**What I have tried and what did not work**

I have tried to use the solution as described in the [R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/). The custom `multiplot()` function given on that page renders the plots without legends just fine. However, if one needs only a single legend, that function fails. Since one of the graphs would contain the legend, whereas the other not, the width of both graphs would differ in relation to each other (copy the multiplot function from the [link mentioned](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/) please):

```
multiplot(p1 + theme(legend.position = "none"),p2,cols=2)
```

Another potential solution that I have found is the package `gridExtra`, with this [code example](https://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/arrangeGrob). It almost does what I need, except that the graphs are arranged vertically. I tried playing with the function arguments, but could not figure how to arrange the plots horizontally. Hope someone has more experience with that package/issue. Thanks!

Comment: Who stumbles upon this question: I have asked a very similar one and you might find the answers there very useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814478/ggplot2-multiple-plots-in-a-single-row-with-a-single-legend

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is solution using package `gridExtra` and `grid.arrange()`. First, make three plots - one with legend (p1.leg) and two without legends.

```
p1.leg <- ggplot(dsamp,aes(price,carat,colour=clarity))+geom_point()
p1<-ggplot(dsamp,aes(price,carat,colour=clarity))+geom_point()+
      theme(legend.position="none")
p2 <-ggplot(dsamp,aes(price,depth,colour=clarity))+geom_point()+
     theme(legend.position="none")
```

Now you can get just legend from the first plot with function `g_legend()` that I borrowed from @Luciano Selzer answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883844/inserting-a-table-under-the-legend-in-a-ggplot2-histogram).

```
g_legend <- function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

leg<-g_legend(p1.leg)
```

Now you can combine both plots and legend with functions `arrangeGrob()` and `grid.arrange()`. In `arrangeGrob()` you can set widths for columns to get desired proportion between plots and legend.

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(arrangeGrob(p1,p2),leg,ncol=2,widths=c(5/6,1/6)))
```

[image]

### UPDATE

To put all plots in the same row:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1,p2,leg,ncol=3,widths=c(3/7,3/7,1/7)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Didzis. Unfortunately, this is not what I need. It is the solution which is mentioned in the example for the `gridExtra` package (at least it has the same result). What I need is to have these graphs and legend arranged horizontally, not vertically. Could you possibly modify the `grid.arrange()` call to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Just add `ncol=2` to the `arrangeGrob(p1, p2)` part of the code. (e.g. `arrangeGrob(p1, p2, ncol=2)`).

Comment: Updated my answer to put all plots in one row.

Comment: you don't have to manually guess the legend width: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs