# ggplot2: multiple plots in a single row with a single legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gridextra

I want a combined plot of two plots + their legend like this:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]    
p1 <- qplot(price, carat, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)
p2 <- qplot(price, depth, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)
g <- ggplotGrob(p1 + theme(legend.position="bottom"))$grobs
legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1+theme(legend.position="right"),p2+theme(legend.position="none"),legend,ncol=3,widths=c(3/7,3/7,1/7)))
```

[image: expected output]

However I do not want to guess the width of the plots and legends (and specify `ncol`) but have it extracted from `p1` and `p2` [as shown here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs).

So I expect I would need something like this (adapted code from the link):

```
grid_arrange_shared_legend_row <- function(...) {
  plots <- list(...)
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position="right"))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
  grid.arrange(
    do.call(arrangeGrob, lapply(plots, function(x)
      x + theme(legend.position="none"))),
    legend,
    ncol = length(plots)+1,
    widths = unit.c(rep(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, length(plots)), lwidth))
}
grid_arrange_shared_legend_row(p1, p2)
```

but this is not arranging the two plots in one row but rather one column:

[image: not what I want]

This question is similar [to this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963137/ggplot2-multiple-plots-with-different-variables-in-a-single-row-single-groupin) but different in that I am asking for the adapted widths as well. I am using code extracts both from that question + answer and the github.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you use facetting?

```
library(reshape2)
dmelt <- melt(dsamp, id.vars = c("price", "clarity"), measure.vars = c("carat", "depth"))
ggplot(dmelt, aes(x = price, y = value, color = clarity)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you, this works great actually. Maybe you should answer the other question as well with this same code? It was quite high up my google results and would be a great reference for future users!

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` as @Roland suggested.

A while ago I had to use the `grid.arrange` (I wanted the labels on the y-axis to be colored in an specific order) and this is the function I came up with:

```
ggplot_shared_info <- function(...) {
  plots <- list(...)
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]])$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  title <- g[[grep("plot.title", sapply(g, function(x) x$name))]]
  xaxis <- g[[grep("axis.title.x", sapply(g, function(x) x$name))]]
  yaxis <- g[[grep("axis.title.y", sapply(g, function(x) x$name))]]

  lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
  theight <- sum(title$height)
  xheight <- sum(xaxis$height)
  ywidth <- sum(yaxis$width)

  grid.arrange(
     title,
     arrangeGrob(
       yaxis,
       do.call(arrangeGrob, c(lapply(plots, function(x)
         x + theme(legend.position="none", 
                   plot.title = element_blank(),
                   axis.title = element_blank())), 
         nrow = 1)),
       legend,
       nrow = 1,
       widths = grid::unit.c(ywidth, unit(1, "npc") - ywidth - lwidth, lwidth)
     ),
     xaxis, 
     heights = grid::unit.c(theight, unit(1, "npc") - theight - xheight, xheight),
     ncol = 1
  )
}
```

**Edit:** now user can determine which of the listed plot elements should be 'joined'.

```
ggplot_shared_info <- function(..., elements = c('legend', 'title', 'yaxis', 'xaxis')) {
  plots <- list(...)
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]])$grobs

  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
  title <- g[[grep("plot.title", sapply(g, function(x) x$name))]]
  theight <- sum(title$height)  
  xaxis <- g[[grep("axis.title.x", sapply(g, function(x) x$name))]]
  xheight <- sum(xaxis$height)
  yaxis <- g[[grep("axis.title.y", sapply(g, function(x) x$name))]]
  ywidth <- sum(yaxis$width)

  plots <- lapply(plots, function(x, elements = elements){
    if('legend' %in% elements) x <- x + theme(legend.position="none")
    if('title' %in% elements) x <- x + theme(plot.title = element_blank())
    if('xaxis' %in% elements) x <- x + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
    if('yaxis' %in% elements) x <- x + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
    x
  }, elements = elements)
  plots <- do.call(arrangeGrob, c(plots, nrow = 1))

  if('legend' %in% elements) 
    plots <- arrangeGrob(plots, legend, nrow = 1, widths = grid::unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth))
  if('yaxis' %in% elements)
    plots <- arrangeGrob(yaxis, plots, nrow = 1, widths = grid::unit.c(ywidth, unit(1, "npc") - ywidth))
  if('title' %in% elements) 
    plots <- arrangeGrob(title, plots, ncol = 1, heights = grid::unit.c(theight, unit(1, "npc") - theight))
  if('xaxis' %in% elements)     
    plots <- arrangeGrob(plots, xaxis, ncol = 1, heights = grid::unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - xheight, xheight))
  grid.arrange(plots)
}
```

Comment: This works nicely, and should be even more general, thanks! Note that a missing title will lead to an error, i.e. for the given example should be called as: `ggplot_shared_info(p1+ggtitle("p1"), p2)`

Comment: Hadn't thought about that! I'll try to edit my code so that the user can determine which elements of the plot he whishes to be 'shared'.