# Inserting a table under the legend in a ggplot2 and saving everything to a file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data.frame which I would like to plot with ggplot2:

```
df = data.frame(mean=c(1.96535,2.133604,1.99303,1.865004,2.181713,1.909511,2.047971,1.676599,2.143763,1.939875,1.816028,1.95465,2.153445,1.802517,2.141799,1.722428),
sd=c(0.0595173,0.03884202,0.0570006,0.04934336,0.04008221,0.05108064,0.0463556,0.06272475,0.04321496,0.05283728,0.05894342,0.05160038,0.04679423,0.05305525,0.04626291,0.0573123),
par=as.factor(c("p","p","m","m","p","p","m","m","m","m","p","p","m","m","p","p")),
group=as.factor(c("iF","iF","iF","iF","iM","iM","iM","iM","RF","RF","RF","RF","RM","RM","RM","RM")),
rep=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))
```

This is my code for doing that:

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(factor(rep),y=mean,ymin=mean-2*sd,ymax=mean+2*sd,color=factor(par)))
p <- p + geom_pointrange()+facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 4)+scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","red"),labels = c("p","m"),name = "par id")
p <- p + ggtitle("test")
p <- p + labs(y="log(y)",x="rep")
```

which produces this figure:
[image]

I would like to add this data.frame under the legend:

```
leg.df = data.frame(statistic = c("pp(par)","pp(g)","pp(s)","fc(p/m)"), value = c(0.96,0.94,0.78,1.5))
```

I followed this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883844/inserting-a-table-under-the-legend-in-a-ggplot2-histogram) for inserting a table under the legend in a ggplot2 using this code:

```
g_legend <- function(a.gplot){
    tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
    leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
    legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
    return(legend)
}
legend <- g_legend(p)
grid.newpage()
vp1 <- viewport(width = 0.75, height = 1, x = 0.375, y = .5)
vpleg <- viewport(width = 0.25, height = 0.5, x = 0.85, y = 0.75)
subvp <- viewport(width = 0.3, height = 0.3, x = 0.85, y = 0.25)
print(p + theme(legend.position = "none"), vp = vp1)
upViewport(0)
pushViewport(vpleg)
grid.draw(legend)
upViewport(0)
pushViewport(subvp)
my_table <- tableGrob(leg.df, gpar.coretext = gpar(fontsize=8), gpar.coltext=gpar(fontsize=8), gpar.rowtext=gpar(fontsize=8), show.rownames = FALSE) 
grid.draw(my_table)
```

which produces exactly what I want:
[image]

The only problem is that I cannot get it to print everything to a file. I tried specifying `pdf(<file>)` in front of the entire block of code and `dev.off()` after it, but that doesn't seem to work. So I can only get it to print to the R screen.

So I guess I should be handling the legend part differently but I have no idea how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use the second solution in the link with `arrangeGrob`:

```
leg.df.grob <-  tableGrob(leg.df, gpar.coretext =gpar(fontsize=8),
         par.coltext=gpar(fontsize=8), 
         gpar.rowtext=gpar(fontsize=8))

### final result
library(gridExtra)
pp <- arrangeGrob(p + theme(legend.position = "none"), 
                  arrangeGrob(leg.df.grob, legend), ncol = 2)
```

Then you can save using `ggsave`:

```
ggsave('plot.png',pp)
```

Comment: Thanks. Two quick follow up questions if that's OK: 1. This solution actually puts the table above the legend rather than under it. How do I fix that?. 2. The are that the plot covers now is too small - the legend and the table seem to push it too much to the left of the figure. Any idea how to control that?

Comment: pp <- arrangeGrob(p + theme(legend.position = "none"),arrangeGrob(leg.df.grob, legend), ncol = 2) results with this error: "Error in arrangeGrob(leg.df.grob, legend) : input must be grobs!" Any idea?

Comment: Thanks. This, in combination with [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18407452/2173340), fixed my problem of saving plots created by 'ggplot2' using 'gtable' with 'ggsave'.